# Entity Framework Type configuration integer range

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-annotations, fluentvalidation, ef-fluent-api

I have recently assigned the a new project and i have decided to follow [this](http://chsakell.com/2015/02/15/asp-net-mvc-solution-architecture-best-practices/) for the architecture . Now i have a class like this

```
public class Course
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [Display(Name = "Number")]
    public int CourseID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Range(0, 5)]
    public int Credits { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Department")]
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }

    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Instructor> Instructors { get; set; }
}
```

Now i want to take out the `DataAnnotations` and put them in as separate class using `EntityTypeConfiguration` configuration classes, something like this

```
    public class CourseConfigurations : EntityTypeConfiguration<Model.Course>
{
    public CourseConfigurations()
    {
        ToTable("Courses");
        Property(d => d.ID).IsRequired();
        Property(d => d.Title).HasMaxLength(50);
        Property(d => d.Credits);
    }
}
```

Now how do i put those `int` and `string` range in configuration classes ?
Is it possible to do it here or i have to do it in `ModelView` ? How can i differentiate which validation i will do where ?

Any help will be greatly appreciated ,I am new to MVC and all these patterns so bear with me please :).

Comment: I use data annotations in my ViewModel for validation/presentation and the fluent api for model creation concerns (foreign keys, index, data type,etc.). That way my entity models stay POCO and SoC is attained.

Comment: Yea i was also thinking in this way, is there any article where i can find all the possibilities for FluentAPI with examples ?

Comment: Anyone ? Any reference for Fluent API for this purpose ?

Comment: first hit on google: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx